# Log4net stopped writing to the event log

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

My application uses Log4net to write to the event viewer.  Here's the log4net section of my program's App.config file:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
        <applicationName value="CarSystem" />
        <logName value="CarSystemLog" />
        <threshold value="DEBUG" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Now, these settings were working fine up until about 12:30 pm the day before yesterday.  Suddenly, (just when I need to review the messages in the log, of course) it stopped writing to the log file.

The custom event log is in the viewer.  I've rebooted the machine today, but still nothing new is going into the log.  I increased the maximum log size to 10880 KB.

Why isn't log4net writing to my log file any more?

Comment: Did someone or something change permissions to the folder where the log file is being written?

Comment: Not to my knowlege.  It's my development workstation and I'm an admin on it.  I know I didn't change it.  I'll have to check to see if someone did something through some kind of SMS tool, but let's pretend the answer is no.

Comment: Well, if you can rule out environmental concerns, the most obvious thing that comes to mind is an unhandled exception is preventing the logging code from executing. Given the "just when I needed to review..." statement, it leads me to believe something is going wrong somewhere.  If you know the logging code is executing I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back to the Log4Net documentation and noticed this statement:

> it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.

Well, I had the XmlConfiguration attribute in my AssemblyInfo.cs and a call to `LogManager.GetLogger` in the code, but it was after a call to start a monitoring object I had added to the constructor of my WPF applicaton's `App` object.  I realized that the logging stopped after I had added this call when I read this statement and reviewed the code.

So I moved the call to `LogManager.GetLogger` to be the very first statement in the `App` constructor and the logging began again.  Hallelieuia!

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than looking for a solution, better find the cause.

I suggest you enable log4net's internal debug logging to **file** (any file) and it will dump it's troubles there. I've used this many times when my log files (should be same thing for Event Log) didn't show up.

Instructions on how to configure it [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug).

Quick steps:

- Add this to your app.config:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
     <appSettings>
         <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
     </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

- Add this too to the config (`configuration` section).

```xml
 <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
              <add 
              name="textWriterTraceListener" 
              type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
              initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Any issues with permissions or whatever will then be logged to the trace file.

Comment: I tried making these changes but there are no message in the Debug Output window about error in log4net.  I'm trying to fix other issues right now, and I will get back to it, but the lack of helpful information is frustrating.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: There has to be at least some initialization lines, at the beginning. Can you please double check the configuration?

Comment: Yes, there were initialization lines.  I meant to say there were no error messages or anything useful in figuring out why the messages aren't going to the event log.

Comment: Make sure that the process you are running has write access to the path you set for the trace file otherwise it won't be created.

Comment: In last one year log4net proved to be the biggest pain in my life, I am about to cry. My manual dirty logging would be 1000 times better than using log4net. Couldn't find a university either who would offer a PhD program in using log4net. Not requesting anybody to help me. Just expressing my frustration with it.